# SpEL Cannot Be Cast to Map

Tags: java, spring

Having read the documentation on "[Inline Maps](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-inline-maps)" for Spring Expression Language, I am passing an object to a SpelExpressionParser and `.toString()`ing the `Object`, so to speak; however, in doing so, I am receiving the following error:

> org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression cannot be
>   cast to java.util.Map

The `Object` passed to as the argument to the `.parseExpression` function is the result of the annotation `@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#object, {name: 'roofus', animal: 'dog'})` "affixed" to a method.

Through the `PermissionEvaluator` [interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/PermissionEvaluator.html) implementation, it is passed in its `Object` form to a method:

```
private boolean doSomething (Object animal) { //....
```

Within this method is found an `@Autowired` `SpelExpressionEvaluator`. This is used in the following way:

```
Map animalMap = (Map) parser.parseExpression(animal.toString());
```

Through debugging, I know that the `.toString()` method results in: `{name=roofus, animal=dog}`

Resulting in the aforementioned error. Am I missing something? The goal is to be able to pass in a "JSON"-esque `String` (as specified by the linked documentation) for evaluation purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animal` is already a `Map` (notice the formatting in the OP of the `.toString()` result) and not in the correct format expected by the parser. In this case, you don't even need the parser if the objective is to retrieve information from the `Map`:

```
((Map<String, String>)animal).get("animal")
```

So, in response to the solution proposed by Artem Bilan, this would actually work:

```
Map animalMap = (Map) parser.parseExpression("{name: 'roofus', animal: 'dog'}").getValue();
```

However, again, what is actually received (and the cause of the problem in the OP) is: `parser.parseExpression("{name=roofus, animal=dog}")`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem that `parser.parseExpression` can't return `Map` independently of circumstances .

Looks like you misunderstood the architecture a bit. The `SpelParser` is for building `Expression` object from the the `String`. After that you can `evaluate` that expression using one of its `getValue()` method.

So, only after the evaluation you can get your `Map` object:

```
Expression expression = parser.parseExpression("{name: 'roofus', animal: 'dog'}");
Map map = expression.getValue(Map.class);
```

Comment: That could actually be reduced to one line:
`Map map = parser.parseExpression("{name: 'roofus', animal: 'dog'}").getValue(Map.class)` (as they do in the doc.s). See my answer, below. I haven't accepted my own answer, yet, as I don't know that it is a complete answer.